# Disable indentation after pressing enter

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, tabbing

I just recently started using Intellij and I do like it but there is one thing that bugs me to no end... Tabbing when I press enter. So for example I have this:

```
public class Reference
{
    public static final string Variable = "Variables are cool"
}
```

Well when I press enter to type another line it auto indents like so:

```
public class Reference
{
    public static final string Variable = "Variables are cool"
        public static final string Variable2 = "Another variable"
}
```

Why? I can't find a setting to remove that, anyone know where it is?

I'd like to to be like this:

```
public class Reference
{
    public static final string Variable = "var"
    public static final string Variable2 = "var2"
}
```

Comment: Do you actually not end your statements with a semicolon or is that just a sloppy version of your code?

Comment: Fix that please, that does not help the question at all. If you have a correct syntax, IntelliJ will not indent your code in this case using standard settings

Comment: It seems that if I put a semicolon is doesn't do it, but if I put a semicolon before typing like doing ";" then start typing behind it then it does it.

Comment: Well. Closing and re-opening intellij seems to have fixed it... Not sure why that happened!

Comment: Of course, in this case the statement is continued in the next line. Besides the fact that you should write multiple statements in one line, this is a common way of formatting in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't end your statement - IntelliJ assumes, the next line is a continuation. When you put a semicolon at the end of the line, IntelliJ uses correct indents:

```
public class Reference
{
    public static final String Variable = "Variables are cool";
    public static final String Variable2 = "Another variable";
}
```

Also, write `String` with a capital `S`.

Comment: Alternatively, use Ctrl-Shift-Enter (Command-Shift-Enter on Mac) to have IntelliJ autocomplete the currently line, adding the semicolon if needed, and advancing to the next line.